# Nil object error when using OmniAuth (which normally works)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, omniauth

I am having a weird error when using Omniauth. This appears to have little to do with my code.

Is this the result of Twitter returning some weird deformed object?

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

oa-oauth (0.1.6) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:24:in `callback_phase'
oa-core (0.1.6) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:27:in `call!'
oa-core (0.1.6) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:19:in `call'
oa-core (0.1.6) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:30:in `call'
haml (3.0.24) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
```

Comment: Did you add the necessary callback route? i.e. match '/auth/:provider/callback', :to => 'sessions#create'

Comment: Yes, because it normally works. That is why it is so weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. I highly suspect that it is a deformed return by Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. clearing the browser cache solved it.

slothistype